# Override LocationResourceManager properties example

Tags: c#, inheritance, botframework

I'm using the open source BotBuilder-Location control to have localized prompts.
As per the doc, we need to inherit [LocationResourceManager](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder-Location/blob/master/CSharp/BotBuilderLocation/LocationResourceManager.cs) class to achieve this. I'm new to C# and here is what I did

```
public class MyLocationResourceManager: LocationResourceManager
{
    public new string TitleSuffix = "New message";
}
```

Then I passed an instance of MyLocationResourceManager in the constructor of LocationDialog.
This is not working and the bot displays "Type or say an address" instead of "New message". Please help me out here!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to override the property :

```
public override string TitleSuffix
{
    get
    {
        return "The text you want to see";
    }
}
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.